# Calculate ${e^{At}}$ of $A = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}} i&j&k\\ i&j&k\\ i&j&k \end{array}} \right)$ knowing that $i+j+k=0 $

Tags: matrix-exponential

How to calculate ${e^{At}}$ for a matrix $A = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
i&j&k\\
i&j&k\\
i&j&k
\end{array}} \right)$ knowing that $i+j+k=0$

answer:

if you calculate  $A^2$ you get

$${A^2} = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{i\left( {j + k + i} \right)}&{j\left( {i + j + k} \right)}&{k\left( {i + j + k} \right)}\\
{i\left( {j + k + i} \right)}&{j\left( {i + j + k} \right)}&{k\left( {i + j + k} \right)}\\
{i\left( {j + k + i} \right)}&{j\left( {i + j + k} \right)}&{k\left( {i + j + k} \right)}
\end{array}} \right) = 0$$
This is a nilpotent matrix with order 2 and hence easy to get the exponential.

Comment: What is $A^2$??

Comment: @Phicar are you saying it is nilpotent matrix of order 2 ?

Comment: Not saying anything. You tell us. What would that imply for the exponential?

Comment: @Phicar why downvoting?

Comment: I didn't actually, but I would guess is because you did not show any work on your question.

Comment: More generally one could diagonalize $A=T D T^{-1}$ and then compute $\exp(A)$ as $T\exp(D) T^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, aplying the definition of matrix exponential is hard, but if you know that your matrix is nilpotent $A^2=0$ then your definition becomes trivial:
$$e^{At}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{A^nt^n}{n!}=I_3+At=\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1+it&jt&kt\\
ti&1+tj&tk\\
ti&tj&1+tk
\end{array}} \right)$$